# Directory problems with Sass in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, sass

I am trying to use Sass with my Node.js project. However, my Sass file isn't getting compiled. My folder structure is as follows:

```
Project Folder--- Public
                   |
                   |
             ---------------
             |             |
             |             |
          SASS            CSS
```

My Sass files are in the `SASS` folder, and I want them to be compiled into CSS in the `CSS` folder. In my main index.js file I have included Sass middleware as follows.

```
var sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');
app.use(sassMiddleware({
    src: './public/scss/',
    dest: './public/css',
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
}))
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
[sass]  skip: /admin nothing to do
[sass]  skip: / nothing to do
[sass]  skip: /admin nothing to do
[sass]  skip: /admin/all nothing to do
```

How can I fix it?